# Conditional formatting rows to change color of row based on drop list selection, in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am lookg for some help with what I thought would be an easy task. I have a worksheet of 200+ rows by 12+ columns. Based on a drop list selection in of the columns, I would like that corresponding row to change color. I have 4 choices with 1 color each. I was able to do it the first column using conditional formating with a new formula:

ex. =IF($Y$2="Multimedia", TRUE, FALSE)

then the format I selected the color yellow. So then row 2 will turn yellow.

I added the other three formulas and it works perfectly for the first row but I cannot figure out a way to pull down to the entier sheet. When I do so, every row roots itself to the first row. How can I use this formatting in the entier sheet without having to do manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$Y$2 is an absolute address. The `$` tells Excel to not change this address, regardless of how you copy/drag the cell reference around. Change it to `Y2` and you should be able to do the drag-fill operation.

Comment: Actually, you’ll probably want to keep the absolute column and just use a relative row, i.e. `$Y2`, or extending the scope of the format will also offset the column reference.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that.